# How should GnuPG's `--desig-revoke` command be used?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, public-key

How should the GnuPG command `--desig-revoke` be used, and in which cases should you use it? According to the manual:

> **--desig-revoke *name***
>   Generate a designated revocation certificate for a key. This allows a user (with the permission of the keyholder) to revoke someone else's key.

And there is a related action in `--edit-key`:

> **addrevoker**
>   Add  a  designated revoker to the key. This takes one optional argument: "sensitive". If a designated revoker is marked as sensitive, it will not be exported by default (see export-options).

Second, is this ability to allow someone else to revoke your PGP key GnuPG-specific, or is it part of the OpenPGP standard?

Comment: Searching for information on the command is difficult, as most pages that appear in a Google search are man pages rather than explanation or guides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Delegating revocations

> How should the GnuPG command `--desig-revoke` be used?

The command `--desig-revoke` adds a special kind of signature to your public key which allows another key (which you specify) to create revocation certificates for your key at a later date. Running the command does not actually create a revocation certificate, it just publicly allows others to do so. Regard it as a delegation of revocation.

Running `gpg --edit-key`, followed by `addrevoker` does the exactly same thing, but from within the key edit menu.

### Use Cases

> ...  and in which cases should you use it?

This can be especially useful for larger organizations, where central revocation of employee keys might be useful.

I can also imagine that when using shared keys, where only multiple users together can use the key (so the secret key is distributed) might want to use this option, so every user can individually revoke the key. Imagine a situation one of the group died, or they antagonized.

A third use case would be giving a trusted friend the capability to revoke your key, similar to handing over a printed revocation certificate for storing to him.

### Revocation Keys are Standardized

> Is this ability to allow someone else to revoke your PGP key GnuPG-specific, or is it part of the OpenPGP standard?

Specifying revocation keys is defined by [OpenPGP, RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.3.15), so it is not specific to GnuPG.

Comment: If you use `--desig-revoke` (and subsequently upload the generated certificate), you publically announce that a given key is allowed to _generate_ revocation certificates for your key. If you hand over a revocation certificate to somebody, you (physically) enable him to upload a revocation certificate generated by you. `--desig-revoke` does _not_ generate a revocation certificate, it is just a special signature allowing others to create revocation certificates for your key.

Comment: Can either operation be undone (revoke certificate vs designated revoker)?

Answer (score 1):

In case people (like me) get confused, there was some additional clarification provided in "[How to generate the revocation certificate after being made a revoker with GnuPG](https://superuser.com/questions/882217/how-to-generate-the-revocation-certificate-after-being-made-a-revoker-with-gnupg)".  The `--edit-key`/`addrevoker` is used to grant permission for someone else to generate the revocation certificate; that someone else uses `--desig-revoke` to actually generate the certificate.